# How to make grep-find to always open in window where there's *ansi-term*

Tags: emacs, grep, elisp

When I work on a project I always have *ansi-term* with bash shell in one window. Is it possible to direct grep-find to always open in window where I have `*ansi-term*` buffer, if it exists?

I have function that run grep-find over git repo I'm in. I only need to direct the function to open in window where I have `*ansi-term*`.

Comment: Do you mean to use the same window, to use the same frame, or to use the same directory for the command the *ansi-term* has selected?

Comment: @juanleon as I've written in question "same window" (emacs window). I've never mention frame or directory.

Comment: If you really mean window as the Emacs manual defines it, do you want the `*grep*` buffer to replace the `*ansi-term*` buffer?  Or do you want it to split the `*ansi-term*` window and display the `*grep*` output buffer in the other half?  Or do you actually mean to split the frame in which the `*ansi-term*` window is being viewed?  What if it is not active?

Comment: @tripleee I want to replace it, and when I press `q` I want back my `*ansi-term*`, right now it look like `*grep*` show up at random window.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you are requesting, but I have only tested very briefly.

```
(defadvice find-grep (around switch-to-ansi-term activate)
  (let ((b (get-buffer "*ansi-term*")))
    (and b (select-window (get-buffer-window b t))) )
  ad-do-it
  (and b (delete-window)) )
```

Comment: Because otherwise it will split the window and leave `*ansi-term*` visible.  I put that in rather hesitantly but it was in your requirements.  But it needs to be conditional on `(and b)` -- updated the answer.  Thanks for making me think some more (-:

Comment: I don't think it will work for my case because find-grep don't split windows in my case. But I've used your defadvice idea and use it with a function I've created.

Comment: Feel free to take out the `delete-window`, obviously.

Comment: One more note is that if I have few ansi-terms they are named `*ansi-term*<NUM>`

Answer (score 0):

I've created those 2 functions:

```
(defun windows-buffer-match (regex)
  "return window for open buffer that match regex"
  (let ((list '()))
    (walk-windows (lambda (window)
                    (let ((buffer (window-buffer window)))
                      (if (string-match regex (buffer-name buffer))
                          (setq list (cons window list))))))
    list))

(defun window-match-jump (regex)
  (interactive "sBuffer: ")
  (let ((windows (windows-buffer-match regex)))
    (if (not (null windows))
        (select-window (car windows)))))
```

and as @tripleee suggest in his answer, I use it with devadvice:

```
(defadvice find-grep (around switch-to-ansi-term activate)
  (window-match-jump (regexp-quote "*ansi-term*")))
```

Also this function can be use to open grep in window with differnt name then ansi-term.

Comment: `"*ansi-term*"` is not a valid regex -- you'd need to backslash-escape the asterisks.

Comment: This looks like a rather tortured reinvention of the `(select-window (get-buffer-window ...))` code I have in my answer.  Also it needlessly continues the walk even when it already found a match.  If you really want to match by regex, it would make more sense to return a list of matches.

Comment: @tripleee I don't get the error on `"*ansi-term*"`, also get-buffer will don't return current buffer if my window contain `*ansi-term*<2>` so I need to use match. Other issue is that if I have hidden `*ansi- term*` and visible `*ansi-term*<2>` your code will break, it will try to get hidden buffer and will not work.

Comment: @tripleee I've updated the answer, I've used 2 functions and I quote regex.

Comment: Looking much better.  But you could still end up with an `*ansi-term*` buffer which is hidden, couldn't you?

Comment: @tripleee no because I iterete over windows and get buffers from those. So it the same as search in visible buffer list.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a FIFO. In your ansi-term

```
mkfifo ~/ansi
while :; do cat ~/ansi; done
```

and elsewhere

```
grep xyz abc > ~/ansi
```

Comment: -1 The question asks specifically how to cause `find-grep` to open its output buffer in a particular window (I take it the OP really means frame?), not how to achieve vaguely similar effects by way of a workaround.

Comment: @tripleee That's a little harsh to mark it as worse than other answers when there are no others. Sometimes answers aren't perfect and yet they can still provide a clue as to how to do, or work around things.

Comment: Now that I posted a competing answer, I'd unvote, but I can't.  I still stand by the downvote as I feel this does not attempt to answer the actual question, just discuss a rather crude workaround (it requires you to abandon the features of `M-x find-grep` which basically throws out the baby with the batwater IMHO).